# Printing to table form from a list and a nested list

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, iteration

[pset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1gFG.jpg)Here is my code so far:

```
MEDALS = 3
COUNTRIES = 8
# Create a list of country names.
countries = [ "Canada", "Italy", "Germany", "Japan",
            "Kazakhstan", "China",
            "South Korea", "United States" ]
# Create a table of medal counts.
counts = [
            [ 0, 3, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 1 ],
            [ 0, 0, 1 ],
            [ 1, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 1 ],
            [ 3, 1, 1 ],
            [ 0, 1, 0 ],
            [ 1, 0, 1 ]
        ]

print('       Country  Gold  Silver  Bronze  Total')
for v in countries:
    country = v
    print("{:>13}".format(country))
for row in range(COUNTRIES):
    for col in range(MEDALS):
        print(counts[row][col],end = ' ')
    print('')
```

Supposed to solve this without using any imported modules. How can I do this and please explain it to me? thank you so very much.

I can get the numbers to print under the table but not in the columns of the table like it is supposed to be.

Comment: In what way it does not work? What's the error message?

Comment: Well it works but the numbers of medals just prints under the table that ive made so far

Comment: I included the problem for this in the link 'pset'

Comment: Check out what `zip(countries, counts)` gives you back.

Comment: Where do I add the zip function to try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main trick here is to join the corresponding countries with their medal counts and iterate over that as a single thing.

```py
for country_name, medal_counts in zip(countries, counts):
    gold, silver, bronze = medal_counts
    total = sum(medal_counts)
    print(country_name, gold, silver, bronze, total)
```

Note that there are lots of ways to get the same results as `zip()`.

For example:

```py
for index in range(len(countries)):
    country_name = countries[index]
    medal_counts = counts[index]

    gold, silver, bronze = medal_counts
    total = sum(medal_counts)
    print(country_name, gold, silver, bronze, total)
```

`zip()` just does it for you.

Once you get that far, you more or less have the full answer and just need to use a nice format template. To polish it off, lets use a format template like the one you started to use.

```py
# Create a list of country names.
countries = [
    "Canada",
    "Italy",
    "Germany",
    "Japan",
    "Kazakhstan",
    "China",
    "South Korea",
    "United States"
]

# Create a table of medal counts.
counts = [
    [ 0, 3, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1 ],
    [ 1, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1 ],
    [ 3, 1, 1 ],
    [ 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 1 ]
]

## -----------------
## Now we just need to make it look nice
## -----------------
template = "{country_name:>15} {gold:>8} {silver:>8} {bronze:>8} {total:>8} "
## -----------------

print(template.format(country_name="", gold="Gold", silver="Silver", bronze="Bronze", total="Total"))
for country_name, medal_counts in zip(countries, counts):
    gold, silver, bronze = medal_counts
    total = sum(medal_counts)
    print(template.format(country_name=country_name, gold=gold, silver=silver, bronze=bronze, total=total))
```

That will give you:

```
                    Gold   Silver   Bronze    Total
         Canada        0        3        0        3
          Italy        0        0        1        1
        Germany        0        0        1        1
          Japan        1        0        0        1
     Kazakhstan        0        0        1        1
          China        3        1        1        5
    South Korea        0        1        0        1
  United States        1        0        1        2
```

Comment: wow thank you so much, Im familiar with zip but I didnt think to use it here. Also, what is the syntax you used to format the skew of the countries? like what is it called when you type  '{country_name:>15}'?

Comment: That is a format string spec. check out [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Your code now says: print all countries `for v in countries:` then print all medals `for row in range(COUNTRIES)`, to print table you need to nest your second loop within first loop.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the indentation of your second `for` loop is incorrect.

### Code

```
MEDALS = 3
COUNTRIES = 8
# Create a list of country names.
countries = ["Canada", "Italy", "Germany", "Japan",
             "Kazakhstan", "China",
             "South Korea", "United States"]
# Create a table of medal counts.
counts = [
    [0, 3, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [3, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1]
]

print('       Country  Gold  Silver  Bronze  Total')
for row in range(COUNTRIES):
    country = countries[row]
    print("{:>13}".format(country), end=' ')
    for col in range(MEDALS):
        print("{:<7}".format(counts[row][col]), end=' ')
    total = sum(counts[row])
    print("{:<6}".format(total))
```

I have fixed your code, it works fine now.

### Output

[image: Output]

Hopefully this helps, good luck :)